# websocket extension bits

Tags: python, http, websocket

I'm writing a websocket server implementation in Python, and I'm a little lost on how extension negotiation works.  There is of course the Sec-WebSocket-Extensions header available for the client to request extensions and for the server to allow / reject them.  It's the relationship of these extensions to the RSV1, RSV2, and RSV3 bits that somewhat confuses me.

The deflate-frame extension uses RSV1.  I know of no other extensions.  If / when they are created, how will they map to RSV1, RSV2, and RSV3?  And why is this information transmitted with every WebSocket frame?

I've probably been negligent in not poring over the RFC with a magnifying glass, but I can't seem to find anything that explains this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSocket extensions are specified in RFCs different from the WebSocket protocol itself (RFC6455).

The WebSocket working group has "unadopted" the per-frame compression instead of per-message compression:

- http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg09816.html
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-permessage-compression-04